# Cannot read data from Entity because of LazyInitializationException

Tags: hibernate, spring-data, hibernate-onetomany

I have to show some data in a front end which is combined from two entities. These two entities have a relationship like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="T_LOAD_ORDERS")
@Data
public class LoadOrders {
    .
    .
    .
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="SUPERVISOR")
    private MdUser supervisor;
    .
    .
    .
}

@Entity
@Table(name="T_MD_USER")
@Data
public class MdUser {

    @Id
    @Column(name="USER_ID")
    private String userId;
    .
    .
    .
    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="USER_ID")
    private List<OrderStates> orderStates;

    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="SUPERVISOR")
    private List<LoadOrders> loadOrders;

    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="USER_ID")
    private List<Staff> staffs;
}
```

So I must get the data from the LoadOrders entity and the userId from MdUser. I use a JPARepository from Spring so I call findAll() on the LoadOrders entity. So far this works fine. But when I add these few lines of code:

```
if (loadOrderEntity.getSupervisor() != null) {
    MdUser user = loadOrderEntity.getSupervisor();
    this.supervisor = user.getUserId();
} else {
    this.supervisor = null;
}
```

I get this exception:

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: de.XXXX.XX.XXXX.data.entity.MdUser.orderStates, could not initialize proxy - no Session
```

Well, I thought I'd be very clever changing the named fetchtype to eager but as the code shows, there are more lazy fetchings in this entity. Changing them all to eager sounds pretty silly to me and doesn't work either:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.loader.MultipleBagFetchException: cannot simultaneously fetch multiple bags: [de.fraport.bvd.mobisl.data.entity.MdUser.staffs, de.fraport.bvd.mobisl.data.entity.MdUser.orderStates]
```

So what can I do here?

**EDIT**

After the hint by Piotr Podraza that putting @Transactional to the method that calls the data I changed my code that reads from database like this:

```
@Transactional(readOnly=true)
@GetMapping("/dispo/orderViewList")
private String showOrderList(@RequestParam("page") Optional<Integer> page, Model model) {
    page.ifPresent(p -> currentPage = p);

    Page<LoadOrders> pagedList = orderRepository.findAll(PageRequest.of(currentPage - 1, INITIAL_PAGE_SIZE));
    List<LoadOrder> orderList = service.createLoadOrderPage(pagedList); 

    model.addAttribute("page", orderList);
    model.addAttribute("currentPage", currentPage);
    model.addAttribute("totalPages", pagedList.getTotalPages());
    return "/dispo/orderViewList";
}
```

orderRepository extends JPARepository and the findAll() Method is the implementation provided by Spring. But still it doesn't work.

@EnableTransactionManagement is provided by my JPAConfig class which is imported into the main app class like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Import(value=JPAConfig.class)
public class WebApplication {

    @Autowired
    private JPAConfig config;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(WebApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options here:

1) Keep lazy loading your collections and fix your code so it runs inside a session.

2) Change the fetch type so it loads eagerly - this approach would require change of collection types inside `MdUser` class from `List` to `Set` as you cannot simultaneously fetch multiple bags. More about the problem you can read here: https://blog.eyallupu.com/2010/06/hibernate-exception-simultaneously.html

Comment: Well, I tried number 2 because I don't get where I made a mistake in the configuration. Normally Spring Boot should do this for me.
Anyway, the error message changed, but this seems to be another problem. Thank you for the advice

Comment: Actually the code you provided does not explain the exception you're getting which is thrown when you try to access lazy loaded collection outside of transaction and that is not the case in code snippet you posted. If you use Spring you could mark the method inside which you try to get access to order states with `@Transactional` annotation - that would solve your problem aswell.

Answer (score 0):

To make a `@Transactional` annotation work you must add `@EnableTransactionManagement` annotation into you AppConfig file.

Speaking of `Caused by: org.hibernate.loader.MultipleBagFetchException: cannot simultaneously fetch multiple bags: [de.fraport.bvd.mobisl.data.entity.MdUser.staffs, de.fraport.bvd.mobisl.data.entity.MdUser.orderStates]`

It happenns because in a Hibernate terms you are actually use not `List`s but `Bag`s which are not ordered collections with possible duplicastes. In the `MdUser` class you have two properties that are related with a same property:

```
@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="USER_ID")
private List<OrderStates> orderStates;
```

and

```
@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="USER_ID")
private List<Staff> staffs;
```

so in case of `Eager` fetching Hibernate doesn't know how to evolve them both as Basgs. To Avoid this problem there are at least two ways to make Hibernate resolve these properties as real Hibernate Lists:

1. Add ordering for each entity, i.e (assuming `Staff` has this property)

   ```
   @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
   @JoinColumn(name="USER_ID")
   @OrderBy("POSITION")
   private List<Staff> staffs;
   ```
2. Replace `List` with `Set`. If you don't really need any ordering then
   use `Set` instead of `List` and this automaticaly will force Hibernate
   recognize Collections as a Hibernate Sets. It'll allow to avoid
   an ambiguity during the fetching

Hope it will help

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer. I edited my question to show, how I provide @EnableTransactionManagement. Sadly none of your suggestions work for me. The crazy thing is, when I have only one relation in an entity, lazy fetching works (like in LoadOrders) but not if there are more relations.

Comment: From what I saw a _readOnly_ parameter in `@Transactional` annotation at the controller method, it is a _Spring_ annotation. Maybe it will sound crazy but... try to replace `org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional` with `javax.transaction.Transactional` at the controller layer